# Multiple Google+ Share Buttons on a page

Tags: google-plus

I want to display multiple Google Plus share buttons (each linking to a different landing page) on a single page. The use case is similar to a blog home page having multiple posts, So I need to display the share button within each of the posts.

I've included the following code in each of the posts

```
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="none" data-align="left" 
data-href="${postShareURL}" ></div>
```

When I check the source in the browser, I can see the iframes created for each of the share buttons, also the original div (with class='g-plus') is also not removed. but its not actually visible on the page

```
<div id="___plus_2" style="position: absolute; width: 450px; left: -10000px;">
<iframe ...... ></iframe></div>

<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="none" data-align="left" 
data-href="http://www.example.com/thisPost" data-gapiscan="true" 
data-onload="true" data-gapistub="true"></div>
```

The `left:-10000px` looks like the culprit here, but I don't know why is it coming like this.

What should I change so that all the share buttons are visible on the page.

I know that this is possible, As per the [faqs](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#faqs) on google+ share page

```
Can I place multiple buttons on a single page that all share different URLs?
  Yes. Use the href attribute as specified in share tag parameters to indicate 
the URL to be shared.
```

Comment: It's most likely an issue with your sites design/styling. It would be much easier to identify what's wrong if you linked to a live example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="g-plus-footer" data-href="http://google.co.uk" class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div>
<div id="g-plus-footer" data-href="http://yahoo.co.uk" class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div>
<div id="g-plus-footer" data-href="http://test.co.uk" class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div>



<script>   
    (function() {
      var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```